# Children Can't Access Each Other's File on Latest Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an iPhone 5S and my son has an iPod Touch 5th Generation and we both just updated to the latest version of Minecraft PE (V0.11.0 alpha). Since updating, my daughter cannot join my son's file. Local Server Multiplayer is enabled on both devices but when my daughter selects to join his world, the error following error message comes up: disconnectionScreen.invalidName

The weirdest part is that she has an old iPhone 4 and she was able to get onto his file using that.

Anyone have insight on this?

Comment: It's unclear which devices cannot connect to each other. Could you clarify?

Comment: Which device is your son using?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your name (from options ➡ name) to something with only letters in, and no longer than 10 characters.

Comment: Confirmed this worsk on iPad mini with iOS8.  The player name had a dash and spaces in it.